# Heroku JS error in Rails 5 production app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an issues for 2 months now and none of the answers that I got here in my countless threads about this issue have resolved my problem. So I give it another frustrating try:

It is a JavaScript error that I get when my App runs in production on Heroku.

**The Error that I get in the Browser Console is this:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: ht.each is not a function
at application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js:1
at application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js:1
at application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js:1
```

**When I run my App in production locally I dont get this error, this is because my**

> /public/assets

**folder looks like this:**

```
.sprockets-manifest-a7e0d8d7f0627b40ca52eea9623fee45.json
application-a358e1eb31a8f590691be18692bb2f57be910bbb2c5800a4dcb95a6c56deb358.js
application-a358e1eb31a8f590691be18692bb2f57be910bbb2c5800a4dcb95a6c56deb358.js.gz
application-ea2c1b8977f914f6ea0d3aa17e9a18079d0fd8ab6b9aa1a88609bcaba62135d5.css
application-ea2c1b8977f914f6ea0d3aa17e9a18079d0fd8ab6b9aa1a88609bcaba62135d5.css.gz
bootstrap
rails-c094bc3a4bf50e5bb477109e5cb0d213af27ad75b481c4df249f50974dbeefe6.png
```

**On Heroku the very same folder has these contents:**

```
application-18082fe8586b430e37211d8a126c18df28136b583c39a4a6ceb1418202d665a3.css
application-18082fe8586b430e37211d8a126c18df28136b583c39a4a6ceb1418202d665a3.css.gz
application-8344b3a5f740968bd820e663ceac72950f2c3dbec18583fa38efec5788e87e31.js
application-8344b3a5f740968bd820e663ceac72950f2c3dbec18583fa38efec5788e87e31.js.gz
application-a5ee6c15ec2d7545c56a0340738bf8bf07d80b954e685fd04cff6067f34ec439.css
application-a5ee6c15ec2d7545c56a0340738bf8bf07d80b954e685fd04cff6067f34ec439.css.gz
application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js
application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js.gz
application-baa8861fe552f67418ef50a3fcdbb69e3a2ab43226917999d296f85bb407d3e2.js
application-baa8861fe552f67418ef50a3fcdbb69e3a2ab43226917999d296f85bb407d3e2.js.gz
application-cb3abf099471b60aa6a5318e339b92c962f22034d16f78b0f6700a1a4abf42dd.css
application-cb3abf099471b60aa6a5318e339b92c962f22034d16f78b0f6700a1a4abf42dd.css.gz
bootstrap
```

**On local these JavaScript files are loaded into the site where the Error occurs:**

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-b38817c3e3a3049abb1fc08dd6ae448b23330f8453226efdb074710209474f75.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-3b600681e552d8090230990c0a2e8537aff48159bea540d275a620d272ba33a0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/forum.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-12be097b9a2442b0b6cdcb5146d1d63c00abcde3675ff34d1de6126cb13e6714.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

**But on Heroku the site only loads this one JS file** (which seems to be made of all the ones  that are loaded locally and now conflicting each other but I dont really know)

```
<script src="/assets/application-b030a52a6989f6564d19974180747e99f4ac5a28109188d096b47fc12a38f2cf.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

can someone please help me to get it running on Heroku?

The code in question is the standard "sample_app" by Michael Hartl doing his code 1-to-1 and it works for everyone else more or less but not for me.

I am working on Windows with Rails and Ruby up-to-date

What I have tried:

**#1:** precompiling the public/assets folder and cleaning up then pushing, which is of course silly because git doesnt push this folder but people suggested I followed

**#2:** deleting the folder above and then push it, again same problem like above...

**#3:** rearranging the require statements in my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file **in every possible way**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**4:** many more "solutions" that worked for others which are easily findable on stack overflow when one searches for things like "Heroku Javascript error", "Heroku rails javascript error in production", "Heroku rails DELETE method doesnt work in production" and many more, as I said I am on the search for a solution for 2 months now allready, Ive had plenty of time to try and give up after 2,3 hours of fruitless search.

**#5** This has worked: Copy Paste the code from `/config/environments/development` into `/config/environments/production`

**/config/environments/development**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in
  # config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml
  # for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  host = 'localhost:3000'

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            '###',
    password:             '###',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  # config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

**/config/environments/production**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in
  #  config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either
  #  ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials
  # and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved
  #  to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system
  # (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cafsdfsdble.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com',
  # /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security,
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate
  # queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'mighty-springs-34070.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            '####',
    password:             '####',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to
  # raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new
  # 'app-name')

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: can you post the JS file where the code `ht.each` occurs.  My initial guess is it is loaded before jQuery, but without seeing the JS it is hard to tell.  It weill need to be from the precompiled file, the minified application js file from production will not be readable.

Comment: well I would like to but this is out of my reach because I have no custon JS files only the ones that I include with //require in my application.js file and those are written by others...

Comment: Well you can still look them up in the gems, or look them up by clicking on the js files included when viewing it locally and searching, at least knowing where the issue is coming could help solve it.

Comment: when it helps: `pt.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error Symbol".split(" "), function(t, e) {`

The generated JS file where this is from is 8800 lines long

Comment: We need to see where that `ht` variable is coming from, what is the name of the file?

Comment: its called `pt` now I dont know why. Here you go https://pastebin.com/VZqf4tGv line 913 highlighted through multiple empty lines

Comment: will it really help you though? I have no control over it

Comment: So the error you get now is `Uncaught TypeError:  pt.each is not a function`?

Comment: yes it was ht.each now its pt.each

Comment: @llja What do you see in the browser console when you open the page in browser while in dev env. This will give you quick pointer from where the error comes..

Comment: hi thank you all for helping: you can try it yourself here: https://warm-mountain-15591.herokuapp.com/ The delete method doesnt work when you sign up and log in: you cant log out because the JS doesnt work it sends a get instead of a delete because of the JS errors check out the site for yourself here link again https://warm-mountain-15591.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @IljaKO It is far easy to debug in dev env.. Anyway as per last comment, adding `juqery-ujs` can solve that... then u don't need `rails-ujs` anymore though.

Comment: but rails-ujs should make jquery_ujs deprecated, if I use rails-ujs I dont need jquery_ujs

Comment: @ArupRakshit Everytime I push to Heroku it says Yarn Executable not detected when it somes t precompileing the assets

Comment: I visited https://warm-mountain-15591.herokuapp.com/ and get the JS error "Bootstrap requires jquery." Just because Rails doesn't need jquery doesn't mean that your bootstrap gem doesn't. Add it back and try again.

Comment: hi Ive had a lot of configuration with `require` Statements tested and none have worked like this one where I required in order: `jquery`, `jquery_ujs`, `bootstrap`, `turbolinks` ... Having `jquery` and  `bootstrap` didnt solve the issue for me

Comment: i had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `uglifier` gem. I  downgraded from `4.1.18` to `3.0.4`

Comment: i tried to downgrade uglifier but the probleme still the same, perhaps there is someting else must be done

Comment: Problem solved: it seems downgrading uglifier itself doen't solve the problem. i moved duktape to development, removed `//= require_tree .`  from `application.js` and moved `//= require rails-ujs` and `//= require turbolinks` before `//= require jquery` and `//= jquery_ujs`. hope it helps someone else

Comment: seems kinda redundant to have the Javascript from jquery_ujs AND rails-ujs as they do the same but if it works that way than its fine I guess...