# Cant run assets:precompile on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am developing a Rails app on Windows 10 under Rails 5.2.1 and Ruby 2.4.4p296

I cannot run the command `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Jaiel\Desktop\RubyOnRailsForum>heroku run rake assets:precompile --trace
Running rake assets:precompile --trace on ⬢ warm-mountain-15591... up, run.4644 (Free)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
** Execute assets:precompile
```

Is it even an error? There are assets in the `public/assets` folder on heroku, however the JavaScript files seem to be not working or are conflicting each other as I also have a problem with them. For example links with `method: :delete` dont work in my App on Heroku in production environment.

[Here is a thread about my problem that is maybe related to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138549/heroku-js-error-in-rails-5-production-app)

Comment: _Is it even an error?_ - there is no any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $rake assets:precompile (RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile is the exact rake task)
```

Since precompilation is done in production mode only, no need to explicitly specify the environment.

Update:

Try adding the below line to your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Then run bundle install.

Hope it will work :)