# Javascript in a fresh Rails 5.2.1 app on Heroku doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I think there is a big problem with JavaScript files in Rails 5 apps in Production environment on Heroku. It works locally though

My configuration:

```
Windows:   10 Education
Rails:     5.2.1
Ruby:      2.4.4p296
Heroku:    heroku/7.7.7 win32-x64 node-v10.7.0
postgres:  postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.3
```

I will now present you the steps I made to confirm that it doesnt work and you can try for your self. In the end you will have a link to the bitbucket repo and the app on Heroku.

**Step 1: Creating a new Rails 5 App and switching to the root folder**

```
> rails new my_app --database=postgresql
> cd my_app
```

**Step 2: Generate a controller**

```
> rails generate controller static_pages
```

**Step 3: edit the /app/controllers/static_pages_controller file**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

**Step 4: create the views to show with the actions**

*/app/views/static_pages/show.html.erb :*

```
this is the show view

here is a link to the delete action:

<%= link_to t('logout'), logout_path, method: :delete %>
```

*/app/views/static_pages/destroy.html.erb :*

```
this is the destroy view which is called with a link_to method: :delete
```

**Step 5: edit the /config/routes.rb file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#show'
  get 'static_pages/show'
  delete '/logout', to: 'static_pages#destroy'
end
```

**Step 6: check the routes**

```
> rails routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                     root GET    /                                                                                        staticpages#show
         staticpages_show GET    /staticpages/show(.:format)                                                              staticpages#show
                   logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                                                        staticpages#destroy
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

**Step 7: create the DB and migrate**

```
> rails db:create
Created database 'my_app_development'
Created database 'my_app_test'

> rails db:migrate
```

**Step 8: start the server**

```
> rails server
```

**Step 9: go to localhost:3000/ and click the link presented. the link works and send a delete action to the server**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-03 18:43:52 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#show as HTML
  Rendering static_pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application (12.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 504ms (Views: 486.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started DELETE "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-03 18:43:57 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"10NHmV8N4tF3O0r/YYtKtKmHm3xthGjPAE51osb7L9skCM5ZoM2RoiCtZD4Crh9d69ndTOeNRMmIW28ipI/z9A=="}
  Rendering static_pages/destroy.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/destroy.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 73.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Step 10: create a heroku app(you have to be logged in to heroku on your system)**

```
> heroku create
```

**Step 11: push your work to Heroku**

```
> git add -A
> git commit -m "init"
> git push --set-upstream heroku master
```

**Step 12: open your Heroku app and do like in Step 9 and fail because JavaScript seems to not work correctly**

```
(...) Started GET "/" for 84.147.254.28 at 2018-09-03 16:47:44 +0000
(...) Processing by StaticPagesController#show as HTML
(...)   Rendering static_pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application
(...)   Rendered static_pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.2ms)
(...) Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 13.7ms)
.
.
. 
(...) Started GET "/logout" for 84.147.254.28 at 2018-09-03 16:48:05 +0000
(...) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/logout"):
```

This is either an obvious error on Rails or on Heroku's side as all you see I did was jsut create a fresh new rails app and changed the routes, generated a controller and made 2 views for the controller actions.

Here are the links if you want to check out all the sources for the app and the app deployed to heroku.

You can check the source code here:[BitBucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/Jaiel/my_app/src/master/)

And the app here: [Heroku app](https://rocky-inlet-61318.herokuapp.com/)

Does anyone else has this hardships with Rails and Heroku or is there anything I can do to make it work?

**EDIT**: made the output of Step 12 a bit clearer by deleting unneccessary log information and time stamps

Comment: Where did you get that the error is related to javascript?

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: yes it works locally (**like you can see in STEP 9**) as I said that its failing in production mode but I edited to make it clearer. And I know its Javascript because the app requires "rails-ujs" to work and without it it doesnt work even on local and I get JavaScript errors in production mode whereas locally there are none at all in console. Here is another Thread of mine about this issue to amke it clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138549/heroku-js-error-in-rails-5-production-app

Comment: If you want go through these minimal steps on your windows machine and tell me if you can reproduce the error I would be thankful. There is something wrong with rails at this point imo

Comment: Have you tried looking at the browser console and actually trying to diagnose the javascript error?

Comment: no but the links are there for you to do so. I will try to exclude the duktape gem like  chrismanderson told me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue: It was the `uglifier` gem that caused the problem as it was not working correctly. I am just a beginner and looking back this gem should have been the first thing I needed to check as it does the JS compression.

Now the JS runs perfectly fine. Here is the change I did in the `GemFile` to make it work:

From

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

to

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.4'
```

The `uglifier` gem version was `4.1.18` that caused this JS error in production environment.

Hope this helps others to pin down their JS errors on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `duktape` gem. That is a Javascript engine that's not widely used in the Rails world, but is included by default in a new Windows rails installation, because it's one of the only engines that actually works in Windows. (If you haven't figured out by now, not a lot of Rails windows devs :) ).

I don't think Heroku has great support for it, so when it picks up that engines, the JS silently fails to compile. If you look into the `application.js` file in production, you'll see a bunch of `NaN: "select[data-remote], input[data-remote], textarea[data-remote]", at the top, when you should see things like`                inputChangeSelector: "select[data-remote], input[data-remote], textarea[data-remote]"`.

If you want to get things working, move the `Duktape` gem out of its current spot to the `development` section of your Gemfile, bundle, and redeploy (you can avoid a JS compiler in the main Gemfile for now.

I would also open a ticket with Heroku. Generally, they warn you of common config issues such as this, but when I tried to deploy your app, I got no such warning. I would imagine just hasn't come up for a lot of users.

Comment: I did what you said https://bitbucket.org/Jaiel/my_app/src/master/Gemfile. Put duktape to dev group and pushed to Heroku. There was a line stating `Removing duktape (2.0.1.0)` while deploying. Still a lot of NANs and error and not working link in https://rocky-inlet-61318.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Try creating a completely new Heroku app. I have a hunch there's some deployment setting that got locked in on the first deploy. I would also reach out to Heroku support, they can likely offer more assistance.

Comment: I resolved the issue, it was caused by the `uglifier` gem that has a bug in production I guess