# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu not working in production mode rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I follow rails tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login) to generate sample rails app. But however the dropdown menu only works in development mode. In production mode, nothing happen when I click "Account". I tried below things, still cannot resolve it. Can anyone help me out?
1) pre-compile assets
2) change bootstrap and jquery order in applicaiton.js as someone mentioned

Here is _header.html.erb file code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%=link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Below is my assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require jquery

//= require bootstrap

//= require activestorage

//= require turbolinks

//= require_tree .
```

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

# bootstrap
# gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
# gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'

# jquery
gem 'jquery-rails', '~>4.3'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'

  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'

  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: If I set config.assets.debug = true, it will work. But still cannot figure out why was that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try precompiling the assets before starting your production instance? If not run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just tried, it's not working :(

Comment: move duktape gem to development group then? Sorry that it doesnt work for you but that was amy solution....try maybe other versions of uglifier, at least for Heroku and on ym wndows machine it resolved my issues

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with my Rails app. See here : [Javascript in a fresh Rails 5.2.1 app on Heroku doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154149/javascript-in-a-fresh-rails-5-2-1-app-on-heroku-doesnt-work-properly)

The problem was the `uglifier` gem I changed it from

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

which loaded the 4.1.18 version released a few weeks ago to

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.4'
```

You should change

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

back to false because this loads all the assets one by one instead of minifying them (with `uglifier`'s help) in production like it does in development. The error just comes from the `uglifier` gem not working correctly somehow

Edit:

These are my application.js require statements:

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is my GemFile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.4'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.4'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'faker'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'will_paginate'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'duktape'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

Here is the app I am working for my web development class at the moment:

[Ruby on Rails Forum](https://warm-mountain-15591.herokuapp.com/)

I am also going with the tutorial and am at the password_reset Step of the Rails Tutorial and its working now with this set up...

Rails 5.2.1
Ruby 2.4.4p296
Windows 10 Education

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried it, but still not working. I use Chorme inspect to check and found it shows "Uncaught TypeError: ht.each is not a function".

Comment: This is the exact error that I had. And the uglifier was the solution for that. I hope you did `bundle update` and `rake assets:precompile` if you are on your local machine testibg in production. If not my last solution would be to comment out the line with `js_compressor: uglifier` in your `production.rb` because you are only using external JS and these fail in production BECAUSE the `uglifier` gem fails to do its job right

Comment: Pleade check the links nk I orovided, there is another link at the end of the question to my BitBucket repo. And also check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138549/heroku-js-error-in-rails-5-production-app so you know that I had the exact `ht.each is not a function` problem because of the `uglifier` gem

Comment: Make sure to have `~> 3.0.4` not `>=3.0.4` as your uglifier gem version. It has to be the uglifier because your JS files work fine in development when they are not compressed into one big JS file like in production

Comment: Yes, I did update uglifier ~> 3.0.4 and bundle update/install, precompile, it still not resolved my case. It makes me crazy. BTW, I am using bootstrap 3, rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.1 (actually I tried ruby 2.3.3, still has this issue). This case is very likely caused by js compressor, but still don't know where is the root cause.

Comment: ah bro I just saw that you are missing a ujs engine. paste in a `// require rails-ujs` in your application.js right after the jquery statement

Comment: I edited my answer with my files.If this doesnt help you I am out of answers. Last chance is to comment out  :`config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` in your `config/environments/production.tb`...

Comment: Thank you Ilja KO! I added ujs as you mentioned, but it's still not working. Commented out that js compressor can make it work. Will it slow down app performance? This issue makes me crazy.

Comment: I know how you feel. I dont know why the uglifier gem jsut doesnt work correctly either. Maybe try another JS compressor/minifier or play around with the gem version. Yes it slows it down as every JS file has to be loaded but I would say this is maybe jsut a few miliseconds slower if you are not loading loads and loads of JS files at once. It seems to be random as the 3.0.4 version works for me but not for you. Crazy I say!!!

Comment: Yeh, I will use your solution for now to continue my study. Thank you Ilja KO!